# Facebook login function doesn't executes anything after the login itself

Tags: javascript, facebook

In the following code, I try after the login to execute ajax and redirect,
What is utterly weird is, that it logs me in, but anything that comes after the `FB.login` is ignored!

also I use this exact code in another site and it works fine, withe the ajax and the redirect.

The call to facebook api as asynchronous, and is not included here (it works)

```
$(".joiner").live("click", login);
var button = document.getElementById('fb-login');

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '0000000000000000', status: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            console.log('User is logged in.');
            FB.api("/me", handleMe);
        }
        else {
            console.log('User is not logged in.');
            }
    });
};



function login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            console.log('Login success.');
            FB.api("/me", handleMe);
        }
        else {console.log('Login cancelled.')}
    });
}



function handleMe(response) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'www.url.com',
        data: "uid=" + response.id + "&name=" + response.name + "&gender=" + response.gender,
        success: function(){
            console.log('Ajax successful.');
            window.location = "www.url.com";
            },
        error: function(){console.log('Ajax failed.');}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem some time ago. I could solve it with seting the right url in the facebook app configuration and running the script from this url. It does not work when you try to make a login from, for example, your localhost with a diffrent url setting in the app config.

there is an respone showing the error code, but not response.session.

Comment: thanx, what do you mean "the right URL" i'm trying to run it from outside facebook and get the exact same result. also, what login form you mean? and I didn't understood what you meant in the last phrase.

Comment: I mean that the url which is entered in the facebook app configuration must be the url from which you test your site. so if you enter www.test.com in the app configuration and want to make a facebook login, your page come from this domain. in short: if www.test.com is entered in facebook app configuration it does not work when you test from http://localhost/test.